# What is the best tool for functional testing of a complex web application

Tags: testing, grails, automated-tests, functional-testing

I have a fairly complicated web application that is written using Grails. I am trying to set up a functional testing framework, initially using Selenium, but have run into two problems.

1. Part of the page I wish to test involves a treelike data structure that is displayed using jstree. The problem here is that the action I wish to simulate - the user clicking on a node to display its children - seems to be triggered by a click on a specific co-ordinate within a div, which is proving hard to test. I have managed to work around the problem by opening this node using Javascript passed directly to the browser by Selenium's executeScript() method.
2. The webapp makes heavy use of file uploads, and this is something that I definitely need to test. There is no straightforward way to submit file uploads using Selenium.

What is the best way of going about this? I am considering trying Tellurium (but it's not clear from my reading whether or not file uploads work) or iMacros (on the assumption that a browser extension will handle file uploads better). This can't be a rare situation that I'm in; can anybody suggest a better alternative?

Comment: We're using `functional-test` plugin and just simulate web requests, without browser involved. It might simplify some things.

Comment: It would certainly be nice to be able to test using HTMLUnit. But unfortunately we've found it difficult to test some of the rich UI stuff without actually firing up a browser, and we really want to keep all testing under one framework.

Comment: It doesn't differ much from integration tests. I believe you do have Grails unit and integration tests, so nearly no infrastructure overhead here. Just clearly separate, what is used for what. Sure, `functional-test` will never let you test browser-side logic.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly I am biased, but may I suggest Telerik Test Studio which you can find here: . I just verified we can record and playback clicks on the special expander of a jsTree without any difficulty whatsoever. We also have built-in support for handling file uploads. What else do you need?

Cody,
Test Studio Support Officer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - looks like an interesting product. Unfortunately all our development is done on Linux, so I won't be able to try it out. Also, this is for a piece of open-source academic software, so the cost is a little out of our price range of $0 :-)

Answer (score 0):

We have used Rational functional tester to test Web 2.0 based application using dojo tool kit 1.0 . We used along with our own homegrown framework . It worked well with few exceptions like not very good support for new browsers of Firefox new releases etc.